# Why doesn't .__proto__ = .prototype in this example?

Tags: javascript

I understand that "*`__proto__` is an internal property of an object, pointing to its prototype*" so in the following example I would think that `c2.prototype` would equal `c2.__proto__`. Why do they not have the same value?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var Circle = function(radius) {
                    this.radius = radius;
                    this.doubleRadius = function() {
                        return this.radius * 2;
                    }
                }

                var c1 = new Circle(4);

                Circle.prototype.area = function() {
                    return Math.PI*this.radius*this.radius;
                }

                var c2 = new Circle(5);

                console.log('--- first circle object, created before adding "area" method');
                console.log(c1.radius);
                console.log(c1.doubleRadius());
                console.log(c1.area());

                console.log('--- second circle object, created after adding "area" method');
                console.log(c2.radius);
                console.log(c2.doubleRadius());
                console.log(c2.area());

                console.log(c2.prototype); // undefined
                console.log(c2.__proto__); // Object { area=function() }

            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that `c2.constructor.prototype == c2.__proto__`

Constructors have a `.prototype` property. Instances don't, but they do have `.__proto__` and `.constructor` properties

Answer (score 2):

`obj.__proto__` is short version of `obj.constructor.prototype`, not of `obj.prototype`:

```
console.log(c2.constructor.prototype === c2.__proto__);   //true
console.log(c2.prototype === c2.__proto__);   //false
```

Comment: It's not exactly a short version. You can change the prototype of a single instance of an object and not affect others. It is true that both versions point to the same object (unless you've modified it).

Comment: @JuanMendes What does 'change the prototype of a single instance' means? And pls,show me an example,where `c2.constructor.prototype != c2.__proto__`.

Comment: My comment says, unless you've modified it, I thought it sounded kind of obvious. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/UrqmL/ I created two instances from the same constructor, modified the `__proto__` property of one of them. For the one that's been modified, `console.log(a.constructor.prototype == a.__proto__);` outputs false

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for your time, to make an example. Actually I thought, that by changing you meant kind of `c2.__proto__.prop='blabla'` things,but not changing the `prototype` as a whole.

Comment: @Enginner I do see what you mean. In any case, I've never had a situation where I actually did this (since `__proto__` is not cross browser), or that I wanted to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below.

```
console.log(c2.constructor.prototype);
console.log(c2.__proto__);
```

Acturly, `.__proto__` == `.constructor.prototype` when c2 is a object.

Comment: See my comment on Engineer's answer for a case where this is not true. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/UrqmL/